# Error CS0649, Program will not display a variable in the defined UI

Tags: c#

```
class Program
    {
        public static string playerName;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           playerName = Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void userInterface()
        {
            Console.Writeline("Name:" + playerName)
         } 
    }
```

Been trying to understand where im falling short for a few hours now and cannot figure it out, wondering if any of the SO residents can help me.
Im trying to display a inputted username in a GUI using C# console, I have defined it as a public variable in the class and called it in the method, however its throwing me this exception and displaying a null value?
Any help is appreciated.[Class and Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gECg4.png) [The method im trying to call the variable to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/puaIT.png)

- EDIT the desired aim is to have the program display the users inputted username in the UI at the top of the console

Comment: Please consider posting your code snippet here

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: New to using the site, how am I able to put the snippet into the post? Ive linked two photos using the snipping tool?

Comment: Snippet != snipping tool.  We want a *textual* code block that we could copy/paste into our own IDE to get the same error you are seeing.  See [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) on how to format your code.

Comment: Your program works but the variable is not assigned a value (so variable playername needs a value)

Comment: Is this any better guys? Seems really trivial that theres just something im missing?

Comment: @edelwater does that mean I need to give it a value in the class at the beginning or in the main?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
       static void Main(string[] args)
       {            
          Player player = new Player
          {
            Name = "name coming from your input class"
          };
          UserInterface userInterface = new UserInterface(player);
        }        
   }

   class UserInterface
   {
     public UserInterface(Player player)
     {
        Console.SetWindowSize(220, 55);
        Console.WriteLine("Name: {0}", player.Name);
     }
   }

   class Player
   {
     public string Name { get; set; }
   }

}
```

Or something alike. So you need to provide values for your variables.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, is there any way to explain what the parts of your response mean? Im new to the syntax and cant quite follow what youve written?

Comment: which part specifically ?

Comment: Well, the " public string Name{ get; set;} "and the lines which run like " UserInterface userinterface = new UserInterface(player); " also the reasoning for splitting it into three classes?

Comment: public string Name{ get; set;}  -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties

Comment: UserInterface userinterface = new UserInterface(player);  --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/classes

Comment: I split it in 3 classes so you can define your (a) business objects in one layer e..g player, dragon, house (b) your UI in another layer so e.g. maybe later you want to make it another UI in a web interface

Comment: Thankyou for your help! Solved it now, the program couldnt find the defined route to the variable so was treating it as null, derived this from your solution (userinterface = new UserInterface(player) ) and the links were very useful!

Answer (score 0):

Just call the method  `userInterface()` after this line `playerName = Console.ReadLine();`
this will display the accepted value on console.